# If classical is 120 minutes+ and rapid is 10-59 minutes, then what's 60-119 minutes? 'Slow rapid'?

Tags: fide, time-control

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_chess#cite_note-fide-classical-5) says that FIDE says for tournaments with 2200+ rated players,

> [image]

1. Classical is 120 minutes+
2. Rapid is 10-59 minutes

So what's 60-119 minutes for tournaments with 2200+ rated players? '[Slow rapid](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41478/how-does-fide-define-slow-rapid-fast-rapid)' ?

Answer (score 4):

> Wikipedia says that FIDE says for tournaments with 2200+ rated players

Wikipedia, not for the first time, is wrong. According to the latest [FIDE rating regulations](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/B022022):

> **1. Rate of Play**
>
> 1.1     For a game to be rated each player must at the start of the tournament have the following minimum periods in which to complete all the moves, assuming the game lasts 60 moves.
>
> Where at least one of the players in the game has a rating of 2400 or higher, each player must have a minimum of 120 minutes.
>
> Where at least one of the players in the game has a rating 1800 or higher, each player must have a minimum of 90 minutes.
>
> Where both of the players in the game are rated below 1800, each player must have a minimum of 60 minutes.

Blitz is for games where the game time is 10 minutes or less according to Appendix B of the [FIDE Laws of Chess](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/E012023):

> **Appendix B. Blitz**
>
> B.1    A ‘blitz’ game is one where all the moves must be completed in a fixed time of 10 minutes or less for each player; or the allotted time plus 60 times any increment is 10 minutes or less for each player.

And according to Appendix A:

> **Appendix A. Rapid Chess**
>
> A.1    A ‘Rapid chess’ game is one where either all the moves must be completed in a fixed time of more than 10 minutes but less than 60 minutes for each player; or the time allotted plus 60 times any increment is of more than 10 minutes but less than 60 minutes for each player.

So, the classification is:

Blitz <= 10 minutes
10 minutes < Rapid < 60 minutes
Standard >=60 minutes

Blitz and rapid can be rated for all standards of players but standard time control chess cannot be FIDE rated for < 90 minutes if either player is rated >= 1800 and cannot be FIDE rated for < 120 minutes if either player is rated >= 2400.

There is officially no such thing as "slow rapid". There is just chess which can be rated and chess which can't. Time controls are just a small part of that as the rating regulations make clear.

Comment: ah so standard is 60+ the issue is just it might not be rated between 60-119 and then there's no specific term for 60-119 ?