# What are examples of tournaments/games 60 minutes to below 120 minutes, and how does FIDE classify them?

Tags: fide, history, tournament, time-control

What are some examples of tournaments or games where their time controls [convert](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41479/time-control-conversion-when-it-comes-to-bonus-time-after-eg-40-moves) to at least 60 minutes but below 120 minutes, and then how does FIDE classify them (eg rapid or classical)?

Supposedly they are considered classical, but I've already found 1 tournament & 1 game (I'll post in answer).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [FIDE Laws of Chess](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/E012023):

> **Appendix A. Rapid Chess**
>
> A.1    A ‘Rapid chess’ game is one where either all the moves must be completed in a fixed time of more than 10 minutes but **less than 60 minute**s for each player; or the time allotted plus 60 times any increment is of more than 10 minutes but less than 60 minutes for each player.

So, *every* "tournament whose time controls convert to exactly 60 minutes" is regarded as classical by FIDE. It is just that FIDE will only rate such tournaments for lower rated players. Slower time controls are required for stronger players. For stronger players there is a range of time controls which FIDE will not rate because they are too slow to be rapid and too quick for stronger players.

Comment: This is the whole point. In theory it should be considered classical even if unrated. But in practice, is there any such tournament? I mean, I've already found a tournament, albeit not in regular chess, where 60 minutes is not considered classical.

Comment: Updated question and posted an answer. There are 2 examples now. This is so strange.

Answer (score 0):

1. [2019 WFRCC](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41499/why-was-the-2019-wfrcc-called-slow-rapid-when-its-actually-classical-4515-6%20where%2060%20minutes), won by Wesley So. The so-called '[slow rapid](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41478/how-does-fide-define-slow-rapid-fast-rapid)' (a term undefined even as of 2024Feb29, over 4 years later) games are 45 minutes for the 1st 40 moves and then 15 minutes bonus afterwards. They are considered rapid.
2. [2010 USCC](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/44972/why-is-the-2010-uscc-between-gata-kamsky-yury-shulman-considered-rapid-not-cla), won by Gata Kamsky. The armageddon game had a base time of 60 minutes and even had increment. It is considered rapid.