# Why is the 2010 USCC armageddon between Gata Kamsky & Yury Shulman considered rapid not classical?

Tags: tournament, uscf, armageddon

Similar question: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41499/why-was-the-2019-wfrcc-called-slow-rapid-when-its-actually-classical-4515-6

Related question: [What are examples of tournaments/games 60 minutes to below 120 minutes, and how does FIDE classify them?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41605/what-are-examples-of-tournaments-games-60-minutes-to-below-120-minutes-and-how)

---

It's stated by Jim Ratliff [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/7962/which-side-has-the-advantage-in-an-armageddon-tiebreak-game/32583#32583) that there was a 2013 United States Chess Championship (USCC) armageddon w/ armageddon with 45 minutes base time + [5 second increment](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41576/is-armageddon-always-without-increment). This [converts](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41479/time-control-conversion-when-it-comes-to-bonus-time-after-eg-40-moves) to only 50min, so it's still just rapid. However, apparently, there was a 60 minute armageddon w/ auction [game](https://chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1583077) in the 2010 USCC (also won by Gata Kamsky).

According to chessgames.com [this game](https://chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1583077) is considered rapid just like how [the 2019 WFRCC called 'slow rapid' when it's actually classical (45+15=60)](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41499/why-was-the-2019-wfrcc-called-slow-rapid-when-its-actually-classical-4515-6). It could be worse than Wesley So's case because the armageddon has increment for white. From [thisweekinchess](https://theweekinchess.com/chessnews/events/us-championships-saint-louis-2010):

> Gata Kamsky defeated Yuri Shulman in a **rapid playoff** (Kamsky had black and 25 mins + 5 seconds a move (with draw odds) against Shulman's 1 hour + 5 seconds a move. This came from a bidding process)

**Question**: Why are they calling this game rapid when the base time for white is at least 60 minutes?