# How does FIDE define fast classical?

Tags: fide, chess-variants, world-championship, time-control, chess960

Related: [How does FIDE define slow rapid & fast rapid?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41478/how-does-fide-define-slow-rapid-fast-rapid)

---

Like in the 2019 WFRCC & 2022 WFRCC, FIDE is once again using this undefined term 'slow rapid' in the [2024 Grenke Chess Classic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grenke_Chess_Classic#2024). This seems to be synonymous with another undefined term 'fast classical'.

Link 1 - Chess.com Tournament Page

https://www.chess.com/events/2024-grenke-chess-classic-round-robin#format

[image]

> Players compete in a double round-robin, with two rounds happening each day. Games are in the "fast-classical" time control, with players having 45 minutes for the entire game and a 10-second increment. On the event's last day, players compete in playoffs to determine their final placements, with first playing vs. second, third vs. fourth, and fifth vs. sixth.

Link 2 - Wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grenke_Chess_Classic#2024

[image]

> The tournament returned in 2024 after a five-year hiatus. For the first time the tournament will be played in a rapid time control (45+10) instead of the usual classical.[15]

- The Link '[15]' is the following:

Link 3 - Chess.com Article by Colin_McGourty 2024Feb05

https://www.chess.com/news/view/carlsen-ding-liren-grenke-chess-classic

[image]

> World Champion GM Ding Liren and World Rapid Champion GM Magnus Carlsen top the field for the GRENKE Chess Classic, which returns March 26-31 after a five-year hiatus. Carlsen will be looking to win a third title to add to his wins in 2015 and 2019, with GMs Maxime Vachier-Lagrave, Richard Rapport, Vincent Keymer, and Daniel Fridman completing the six-player field. The games will be played at an unusual "slow rapid" format, with two 45-minute games each day.

and then

> This year marks a return to the original six-player event, with the organizers explaining that the format was curtailed so that it doesn’t overlap with the Candidates Tournament in Toronto that starts on April 4. That doesn’t mean fewer games, however, since the players will play two 45-minute games each day, with a 10-second increment per move. The slow-rapid (fast-classical?) format is one that Carlsen has championed as a potentially better way to decide world championship matches.

Link 4 - twitter chess24 - 2024Mar26

> The games in this year's #GRENKEChess Classic feature a fast-classical/slow-rapid 45+10 time control, so there are two rounds today!

[image]